# Rain coming in bathroom fan vent

Tags: leak, vent, rain

I just moved into a house and during the first rain we had a leak coming from the bathroom vent.  The vent had been broken off above the roof, but was repaired before us moving in.  What problems could we be looking at with this leak?

Not sure if this could be a poor seal or how exactly the vent keeps rain from coming down the vent pipe in the first place?

Comment: Can you get into the attic to see the actual path through the roof? Any pictures?

Comment: If it was repaired as a condition of sale, the "repair" needs to be done over properly on the dime of the seller.

Comment: Is this the plumbing vent pipe, or a bathroom vent fan duct? The plumbing vent does nothing to prevent rain coming down the pipe - any rain coming down the pipe should proceed to the sewer without entering the house. It takes a very shoddy "repair" to screw that up (and having it break at all is HIGHLY unusual in the first place.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal it is for the bathroom fan

Comment: @DanielGriscom I don't have a way to get into the attic just yet, so no pictures for now unfortunately.

Comment: How about some photos of the roof where the exhaust is.  Or maybe it exhausts under an eave.

Comment: It's dark now, but I will try to get some first thing tomorrow morning

Answer (score 2):

Any leak can rot the building, ruin insulation, cause electrical shorts, and cause mold. Water and any part of houses other than the inside of the plumbing don't mix, in general.

Since this is the bathroom fan vent, you have immediate potential for electrical/water interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the repair isn't well sealed to the roof, allowing water to come down the outside of the vent pipe.  Or the spring loaded flap that's supposed to seal it when the exhaust fan isn't on is not closing properly... either because it's a cheap piece of junk or it is damaged. You may be able to spot the second possibility with binoculars, etc from the ground.